# Model to search notes by date

Tags: swift, swiftui, swift-dictionary

How to model notes, so I can search them ,after, by dates? like on the picture.

Firstly, I thought about dictionary with key of type `Date`; but it didn't work to me.
So I've tried the following `String` format:

"04-28-2020" - US calendar

"28-04-2020" - Other calendar

One of the issues - if the telephone changes date style(region dependent), keys remain in dictionary, but aren't accessed any more...

My intuition that it should be the dictionary, but what are the sustainable way to make such a model?
Can it be an array of notes `[Note]`, without keys?

[image]

```
struct Note: Codable, Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    var date: Date
    var title: String
    var description: String
    
    var dateString: String {
        let df = DateFormatter()
        df.dateStyle = .short
        df.timeStyle = .medium
        return df.string(from: date)
    }
    
    // method returns "key" to be used in dictionary
    static func dateKey(for date: Date) -> String {
        let df = DateFormatter()
        df.dateStyle = .short
        return df.string(from: date)
    }
}

class NotesOrganizer: ObservableObject {
    
    // @Published var notes = [Note]() - tried initially
    @Published var notesDictionary = [String : [Note]]()
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var title = ""
    @State private var description = ""
    @ObservedObject var notesOrganizer = NotesOrganizer()
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                Button("Save note") {
                   
                        let key = Note.dateKey(for: Date())
                        notesOrganizer.notesDictionary[key]?.append(Note(date: Date(), title: title, description: description)) 
?? (notesOrganizer.notesDictionary[key] = [Note(date: Date(), title: title, description: description)])
                        
                        print("Date Key: \(Note.dateKey(for: Date()))")    
                }
                
                
                NavigationLink(destination: DetailView(notesOrganizer: notesOrganizer)) 
                {
                    
                    Text("Log history ->")
                        .foregroundColor(.purple)
                        .underline()
                }
            }
            .navigationBarHidden(true)

        }
        
    }
    
    init() {
        UINavigationBar.appearance().setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), for: .default)
        UINavigationBar.appearance().shadowImage = UIImage()
    }

}
```

DetailView()

```
extension Date {
        var tomorrow: Date? {
            return Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .day, value: 1, to: self)
        }
        
        var yesterday: Date? {
            return Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .day, value: -1, to: self)
        }
}

struct DetailView: View {
    @ObservedObject var notesOrganizer: NotesOrganizer
    @State private var dayLabel: String = Note.dateKey(for: Date())
    @State private var chosenDate = Date()
    

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            HStack {
                Button(action: {
                    chosenDate = chosenDate.yesterday!
                    dayLabel = Note.dateKey(for: chosenDate)
                }, label: {
                    Image(systemName: "chevron.left")
                })
                
                Text(dayLabel)
                
                Spacer()
                
                Button(action: {
                    chosenDate = chosenDate.tomorrow!
                    dayLabel = Note.dateKey(for: chosenDate)
                }, label: {
                    Image(systemName: "chevron.right")
                })
                
            }
            .padding([.horizontal,.bottom])
            
            List{
                ForEach(notesOrganizer.notesDictionary[day] ?? []) { note in
                    HStack {
                        VStack(alignment:.leading) {
                            Text(note.title)
                            Text(note.description)
                        }.multilineTextAlignment(.leading)
                        Spacer()
                        Text(note.dateString)
                    }
                }.onDelete(perform: removeItems)
            }
            .navigationBarTitle("", displayMode: .inline)
                
            
            Spacer()
        }
```

Comment: You could use Core Data. Make a Note model, give it date related attributes: a date object, of course, but also maybe a string representing the "month section" or "day section" you need, like note.section (ie "2020/12/31"), or even simple integers. Like: note.year (2020), note.month (12), note.day (31), note.hour, note.minute, etc. Then you would do searches with Core Data's NSPredicate on these attributes.

Comment: @EricAya will this also work for switching dates like in the picture? and the dictionary is not needed?
Like every time, that user switches the date Label, it will search through the data from CoreData?

Comment: If you don't know Core Data yet I suggest using a simple Note struct, with date attributes as I explained, and make it conform to Codable and save the array of notes as JSON. Easy to do, and you will then be able to explore how to do searches on these, with `.filter` for example. If after some time you see you like this system, then move to Core Data, which would be the "pro" version of that. // Store all dates as UTC, always (and/or use ISO format like "2020/12/31" for storing date strings). Then *format* the date using the user's Locale/Calendar before displaying it.